# How do I find the *unsorted* location of an element in a sorted array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am calculating the distance to an Nth nearest neighbor from a set of points in a map. I'm running this on sets of 10s of millions of points, so efficiency is important.

I need a way to track the indices of pairs. Right now my function just returns the distances, after sorting the set of distance calculations. I need a way to track the location of `x` and `y` elements that correspond to each entry in `mindist` My function is below:

```
def pair_dist_calc(x,y, neighbor_num):
    n = len(x)
    x1 = np.tile(x, (n,1)) #constant x along column
    y1 = np.tile(y, (n,1)) #constant y along column
    x2 = np.transpose(x1) #constant x along rows
    y2 = np.transpose(y1) #constant y along rows
    dist = np.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    dist[np.where(dist == 0)] = np.nan

    unsorted = np.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    unsorted[np.where(unsorted == 0)] = np.nan

    np.ndarray.sort(dist, axis=1)

    mindist = dist[:,neighbor_num]
```

I've tried playing with something like `indices = np.where(unsorted == mindist)` but that doesn't work. I appreciate any input, and if there is more info I can provide, please to let me know.

Comment: Use `np.argmin()` instead of sorting.

Comment: @DYZ I need to be able to calculate the Nth smallest term, and argmin only gives the location of the smallest

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the original array, sort it, and find *where* it equals the original array?

```
dist1 = dist.copy()
np.ndarray.sort(dist1, axis=1)
list(zip(*np.where(dist == dist1[:, neighbor_num])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.argsort` to get the indices that would sort an array, without *actually* sorting the array in memory:

```
    ...
    dist[np.where(dist == 0)] = np.nan
    sorted_indices = np.argsort(dist, axis=1)
    sorted_dist = np.take_along_axis(dist, sorted_indices, axis=1)
    mindist = sorted_dist[:, neighbour_num]
```

As far as efficiency improvements, you could probably significantly reduce computation time by using `itertools.combinations` to generate combinations of points. `dist` is a symmetric matrix with `nan` diagonal elements, so you can afford to do fewer than half the number of calculations you're doing at the moment and get the same results.

For example, if `x` and `y` are the x- and y-components of the points you're determining the distance between:

```
def alt_pair_dist_calc(x, y):
    num_points = len(x)
    points = np.stack([x, y]).reshape((num_points, 2))

    point_pairs = list(combinations(points, 2))
    pair_indices = list(combinations(range(num_points), 2))
    # Integer indices of which points each value in `distances` will correspond to

    distances = np.array(
        list(np.linalg.norm(pair[1] - pair[0]) for pair in point_pairs)
    )

    sorted_indices = np.argsort(distances)
    mindist = np.take_along_axis(distances, sorted_indices, axis=None)

    return mindist, sorted_indices, distances, pair_indices
```

Having tested this, I see that you're treating x and y independently, so that example isn't fully applicable, but hopefully it helps.